# Error to load PHP 5.2.6 with Apache 2.2 in Windows VISTA

Tags: php, apache, windows-vista

I Install Apache 2.2 + PHP 5.2 and want to use any MySQL functions get the following error. This expañol and then in translation.

For any extra information just have to ask me my. I do not include data from phpinfo (); since it is much information to include it all.

```
Firma con problemas:
  Nombre del evento de problema:    APPCRASH
  Nombre de la aplicación:  httpd.exe
  Versión de la aplicación: 2.2.14.0
  Marca de tiempo de la aplicación: 4ac181d6
  Nombre del módulo con errores:    php5ts.dll
  Versión del módulo con errores:   5.2.6.6
  Marca de tiempo del módulo con errores:   481b8f4b
  Código de excepción:  c0000005
  Desplazamiento de excepción:  0000abda
  Versión del sistema operativo:    6.0.6002.2.2.0.768.3
  Id. de configuración regional:    11274
  Información adicional 1:  6353
  Información adicional 2:  8a82b40956bba3220ef12e86f3167b20
  Información adicional 3:  51f7
  Información adicional 4:  07102fbf0cd86e7ee52ff4caa94ca357
```

---In English:

```
Problem signature:   Problem Event
    Name: APPCRASH
    Application Name: httpd.exe
    Application Version: 2.2.14.0
    Timestamp implementation: 4ac181d6
    Fault Module Name: php5ts.dll
    Fault Module Version: 5.2.6.6
    Timestamp Fault Module: 481b8f4b
    Exception Code: c0000005 
    Exception Offset: 0000abda
    OS Version: 6.0.6002.2.2.0.768.3  
    Locale ID: 11274   
    Additional Information 1: 6353   
    Additional Information 2: 8a82b40956bba3220ef12e86f3167b20  
    Additional Information 3: 51f7  
    Additional Information 4: 07102fbf0cd86e7ee52ff4caa94ca357
```

thank

**EDIT:**

List loaded extensions:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_zip.dll
extension=php_xsl.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

**EDIT**

This is the error in the apache log

```
[Mon Dec 14 22:10:12 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) PHP/5.2.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 14 22:10:12 2009] [notice] Server built: Sep 28 2009 22:41:08
[Mon Dec 14 22:10:12 2009] [notice] Parent: Created child process 2836
PHP Warning:  Cannot load module 'pdo_mysql' because required module 'pdo' is not loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Mon Dec 14 22:10:12 2009] [notice] Child 2836: Child process is running
[Mon Dec 14 22:10:12 2009] [notice] Child 2836: Acquired the start mutex.
[Mon Dec 14 22:10:12 2009] [notice] Child 2836: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Mon Dec 14 22:10:12 2009] [notice] Child 2836: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

Comment: when does this happen specifically? when you call the MySQL functions? or when you enable the MySQL php extension? this looks like Apache crashing that can be caused by PHP or MySQL

Comment: When I call the function MySQL (mysql_connect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your php.ini, uncomment extension=php_pdo.dll and restart apache.  That solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have run into this problem before.  The php5ts.dll is part of the "thread-safe" implementation of PHP.

I was unable to find any solutions on Google, but after hours of playing around with different versions of the DLL, and even non-thread-safe installs of PHP, I think I ended up disabling the MSSQL module extension (*not* the MySQL module, the **MSSQL** module).  This seemed to fix it, and fortunately I didn't need the MSSQL module anyway.

Comment: I'm not using this module in detail the question that I'm loading modules and the function that creates the problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you try disabling User Account Control and then restarting Apache?

Comment: make the change but the problem continues